# App icon text size isn't fitting

Tags: ios

The text below the app icon isn't fully showing, you can see 9 characters out of the 12, is there any way to alter this making it all fit or maybe have two lines instead of one?

Comment: Do you want to solve this progamatically? If not then this question is off [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

**No**

You can neither change the font size, the letter spacing or number of lines. They all are pretty much fixed.

It is your *annoying* job to find a app name that fits on all devices in the little space that is available.

Note that the font is not mono-spaced, meaning that all character take up different amount of space - you are going to be able to fit a lot more `I`s on the screen than `W`s or `M`s

Comment: is there a way to completely remove it then?

Comment: @red55 Remove the text / your app name?

Comment: @red55, no you need to have a text for your application.